# Wpf MVVM best practices in designing a viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using WPF and am currently designing the getters/setters for my viewmodels. My question is should I be applying the changes to the model as soon as the user changes it (via the setter) or should I be copying the changes over to the model only when the Save() method is called? Eg:

Model

```
public class Customer {
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class CustomerVM {

    //getters and setters are bound to the model.
    public string Name {
        get 
        {
            return model.Name;
        }
        set {
            model.Name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Age {
        get {
            return model.Age;
        }
        set {
            model.Age = value;
        }
    }

    public Customer model { get; set; }

    public CustomerVM(Customer model) {
        SetModel(model);
    }

    private void SetModel(Customer model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void Save() {
        CustomerService.Update(model);
    }

}
```

is this preferred over..

```
public class CustomerVM {

    string name;
    public string Name {
        get 
        {
            return name;
        }
        set {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    int age;
    public int Age {
        get {
            return age;
        }
        set {
            age = value;
        }
    }

    public Customer model { get; set; }


    public CustomerVM(Customer model) {
        SetModel(model);
    }

    private void SetModel(Customer model) {
        //values are copied over to VM when upon initialization
        this.model = model;
        this.name = model.Name;
        this.age = model.Age;
    }

    public void Save() {
        //values are copied to the model when user saves
        model.Name = name;
        model.Age = age;
        CustomerService.Update(model);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an end-user perspective both will function exactly the same, i.e. the data will be saved when the `Save` method is invoked. If this is the correct behaviour for your app, you should use the simplest implementation, which is the first one.

I can see the second implementation being useful if you want to add 'undo' functionality, i.e. allow the user to reset the property values to the current model value.

Anyhow, I typically start with a view model that adapts the model values until I need somethng ore complex.

Comment: What I'm concerned is the best practices as a developer in terms of scalability, readability and maintainability. Your answer makes perfect sense. Guess I'll go for the first approach for now since I don't plan to implement any undo feature for now. Thanks so much for that!

Comment: I would consider simplicity to be a best practice. Upvote / mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: Thanks again. You deserve it.